# How to invoke http external soap service with basic authentication in oracle service bus - Credentials should be stored in CSF KEY STORE

Tags: soap, header, soapheader

I need to invoke a target web service (http) with basic authentication in oracle service bus 12c .

Note1 : http external service invocation was successful in oracle service bus when I selected the option - Basic Authentication  and provided the credentials in Service Account.

Path : BusinessService ->Edit->Transport Details->Authentication->Basic button(.)

Provided the Service Account path for credentails.

Here the requirement is that I shouldn't go with this approach - instead credentials should be stored in CSF Key and use them for re-usability or for best practices.

Also Note - SOAP message doesn't contain credentials in  soap header.